# MapReduce: How can I output key/value pair without newlines?

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I am using a 0 reduce approach to my problem. I wish to preprocess data from one file and then to write it out as another file, but with no new lines and tab delimeters? How can I output my map job that has processed my data with the same file format it came in minus the preprocess.
That is, I have something like this:

Preprocess:

```
<TITLE> Herp derp </Title> I am a major general
```

Post Process:

```
Herp 
Derp 
I 
am 
a
major
general
```

What I want it to do is this:

```
Herp Derp I am a major general
```

I believe the issue is with this line of code:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

However, when I tried, quite naively to do something like:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(null);
```

It obviously would not work. Is there an format class that is provided that I can use to do this? If not, how could I write my own class to just output everything as I want? I am new to hadoop and map reduce.

I have included my map function below. I do not want to use reduce as it would sort between the map and reducer.

```
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);


            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());

                //Did preprocessing here, irrelevant to my problem

                context.write(word, null);
            }
        }
```

Also, I have also googled this and read the apache hadoop api to see if I can gleam an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your mapper class, instead of parsing your line into individual words and writing them out, try sending the entire line to the

```
context.write(word, null);
```

That way it is keeping the entire string you are originally working with together, instead of sending out the line piece by piece.

So, cut your string apart for the preprocess work, then put it back together when you send it out with the context.write command.

Comment: This worked. I was outputting each word as a key/value pair. But each "document" in this file was a line. So once I did that, everything cleared up. Thanks.

Comment: @GeekyOmega: Do you want the output to be ordered according to the input?

Answer (score 0):

If your mapper is writing multiple records containing the individual tokens from a single input line, then you will absolutely need a reducer to group those tokens back together into a single line for output.  You can't do this without a reducer.

Comment: My case is very narrow. My mapper is not writing multiple records. Rather, it is taken one raw file and processing it and returning the values back preprocessed like I want, but now on each separate line.

Comment: How many times do you call context.write() for each call to your mapper.  Sounds like it's more than one.  If you want a single line of output from those multiple writes then you'll need a reducer.

Comment: I will edit my code to show my map function. But I can say no to a reducer. I will destroy the format of my file. Think of it as parsing a book, song, or something. If I use a reducer, this is going to get sorted and destroy any value of me parsing it. I am basically using Mapreduce to parse out some xml tag stuff. I also did some stemming and stopwords. However, I want to keep the rest alone.